# Not updating values in access database

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\sandesh.k\Documents\PARAM_REP.accdb;";
    OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand();
    com.CommandText = "UPDATE LOGI SET [PASSWORD]=@PASS,NAME=@NAME,CAPABILITY=@CAPABLE WHERE ID=@ID";
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", TextBox2.Text);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PASS", TextBox7.Text);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NAME", TextBox5.Text);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CAPABLE", Convert.ToInt32(TextBox6.Text));
    con.Open();
    com.Connection = con;
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "validation", "<script language='javascript'>alert('REPORT CREATED SUCCESSFULLY')</script>");
}
```

Comment: I have tried using keyword also and parameters are in same order but value that I am updating is no reflecting in database ... What is the issue

Comment: Is the ID field a string field in your database?

Comment: @sandeshkadam What are your column types? Have you ever tried this query in your database manager? Is it working there? What is your query looks like when you add your values? We need more details..

Comment: Id column is alphanuneric and capability is numeric password is alphanuneric and name is string

Comment: Now I have updated datatype of rest is string and capability column is numeric but still it's not updating

Answer (score 3):

You didn't told use what is wrong exactly but..

`OleDbCommand` does not support named parameters. *Actually* is supports but it just don't *care* their names. The only matter is their orders.

Set your parameters with same order that you defined in your command as;

```
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PASS", TextBox7.Text);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NAME", TextBox5.Text);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CAPABLE", Convert.ToInt32(TextBox6.Text));
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", TextBox2.Text);
```

Also use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your connections and commands automatically instead of calling `Close` method manually. And don't use `AddWithValue` method. [It *may* generate unexpected and surprising results sometimes](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). Use `Add` method overloads to specify your parameter type and it's size.

```
using(var con = new OleDbConnection())
using(var com = con.CreateCommand())
{
   // Set your CommandText property.
   // Add your parameters with Add method in the same order that you defined.
   // Open your connection.
   // Execute your query.
}
```

Also I *strongly* suspect your `ID` column should be numeric value instead of character type based on it's name.